# Smallest positive integer a such that $5n^{13}+13n^5+a(9n)\equiv 0\pmod{65}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, linear-diophantine-equations

How would you find the smallest positive integer $a$ such that 
$$5n^{13}+13n^5+a(9n)\equiv 0\pmod{65}$$
I simplified the polynomial in terms of $\bmod 5$ and $\bmod 13$ to get $3n+4na \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ and $5n+9an \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$ but from here I'm stuck on how to proceed to solve for $a$.

Comment: this means $$5n^{13}+13n^5+9an\equiv 0 \mod 65$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember *lil' Fermat* can be written as
$$\forall n,\:n^5\equiv n\mod5\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\forall n,\:n^{13}\equiv n\mod13.$$
So we have to solve the system of simultaneous congruences:
$$\forall n,\begin{cases}
13n+9an\equiv 3n-an\equiv0\mod 5\\
5n+9an\equiv 5n-4an\equiv0\mod 13
\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
a\equiv \color{red}{3\mod 5},\\
4a\equiv5\iff a\equiv -3\cdot5\equiv \color{blue}{-2\mod13}\end{cases}.$$
Now, a *Bézout's relation* between $5$ and $13$ is $\;2\cdot 13-5\cdot 5=1$, so  solutions of the system of congruences is
$$x\equiv\color{red}3\cdot2\cdot \color{blue}{13}-(\color{blue}{-2})5\cdot \color{red}{5} \equiv 63\mod65.$$
Thus the smallest positive integer $a$ satisfying the given congruence for all $n$ is  $\color{green}{63}$.

Comment: how did you get that $13n+9an \equiv 3n-an \equiv0\mod 5$

Comment: Just because $13\equiv 3 $ and $9\equiv -1\mod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$65$ divides $$5(n^{13}-n)+13(n^5-n)$$ using Fermat's little theorem

Comment: can you expand on this please?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt , So, $65$ needs to divide $9(a+2)$ But as $(9,65)=1$ we need $$a+2\equiv0\pmod{65}\iff a\equiv-2\equiv-2+65$$